# Convert std::function object to file-name and line-number?

Tags: debugging, c++11

Assuming I have the ability to turn a code pointer (function pointer, program counter, return address, etc.) into a file-name and line-number string, is there any way to convert a `std::function<>` object into meaningful result (e.g. for debug logs or introspection system) pointing at the things that would be called?

Note: I'm willing to use features that depend on extensive use of `#ifdef` to support different platforms provided the platforms supported can be supported robustly.

Comment: Can you define an `unstd::function` with extra instrumentation?  How strange is your use of `function`?  Thinkimg instrumenting during construction prior to type erasure.

Comment: a) I don't control the variable so I can't modify the type. b) the object already contains everything I need to get what I want (the proof being that when I call it, it eventually invokes code at an address of interest) leaving just the question of how to get at it.

Comment: Then I'd start delving into each individual platform's `std::function` header implementation.  `std::function` can be written as a pure-header library, so I suspect it often is.  It will usually be written as a wrapper around a `pImpl` style type-erasure object. You can examine the dynamic type of that internal `pImpl` object (it might have a few specializations) and from that get at the internal stored invokable, which is the thing that would be called. Things get tricky because the `pImpl` type erasure object will be `template`-built for each source invokable, but you might get somewhere...